# External screen snapshot forcibly comes into buttons background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app uses external screen, so in my iPad application i have little controller that works like a remote control for External screen:

[image]

You can see the RemoteControlViewController itself, and it has:
1) Dismiss button
2) Dynamically addable button ( they are used to change what is shown on external screen ).
3) Snapshot of external screen so that user would know what's currently is on External Screen.

On viewLoad ( of my RemoteControlViewController) i take a snapshot of external screen and place it on UIImageView
**But on second opening of RemoteControl - buttons backgrounds are filled with external screen snapshot - HOW, how to prevent this?!**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Add external display controls
[self addExternalDisplayControls];

//Display initial image
[self getExternalDisplaySnapshot];

//Add notification listeners to show/hide external display miniature responsivly
[self setUpScreenConnectionNotificationHandlers];
}

-(void)getExternalDisplaySnapshot
{
//Load screenshot
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
{
    self.iboExternalDisplayNotFoundMessage.text = @"";
    self.iboScaledExternalDisplay.hidden=NO;
    self.iboExternalDisplayControlsPanel.hidden=NO;
    // Get the screen object that represents the external display.
    UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];

    //Detect if retina
    if ([secondScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(secondScreen.bounds.size, NO, secondScreen.scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(secondScreen.bounds.size);
    //Get external windows instance from AppDelegate
    UIWindow   *externalWindow =[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] secondWindow];
    //Render the screen
    [externalWindow.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //Set image to imageview
    self.iboScreenImage.image = image;
}
else
{
    self.iboExternalDisplayNotFoundMessage.text = @"No External Displays are connected.";
    self.iboScaledExternalDisplay.hidden=YES;
    self.iboExternalDisplayControlsPanel.hidden=YES;
}
}

- (void)setUpScreenConnectionNotificationHandlers
{
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidConnectNotification:)
               name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification:)
               name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)handleScreenDidConnectNotification:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
//Just show the screen miniature
[self getExternalDisplaySnapshot];
}

- (void)handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
//Just show the screen miniature
[self getExternalDisplaySnapshot];
}
```

**The problem is that when i dismiss the controller and call it again - buttons backgrounds have images of external screen snapshot! Why? How to prevent this?**

This is my code for adding buttons:

```
-(void)addExternalDisplayControls{
//Adds blood products button
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 50);
UIButton *button = [self createButton:@"button" cords:rect buttonTag:0];
[self.iboExternalDisplayControlsPanel addSubview:button];
}

- (UIButton *)createButton:(NSString *)title cords:(CGRect)cords buttonTag:(int)tag {
UIButtonStyled *button = [UIButtonStyled new];
button.tag=tag;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setStyleName:@"buttonSelection"];
//button.styleName = @"buttonSelection";
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(p_buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = cords;
return button;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I really don't know how this thing happened and how it occurs, but in the end of my Snapshot taking function i added this:

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And all works now like a charm.

Here is Snapshot function:

```
// Get the screen object that represents the external display.
    UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];

    //Detect if retina
    if ([secondScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(secondScreen.bounds.size, NO, secondScreen.scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(secondScreen.bounds.size);
    //Get external windows instance from AppDelegate
    UIWindow   *externalWindow =[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] secondWindow];
    //Render the screen
    [externalWindow.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //Set image to imageview
    self.iboScreenImage.image = image;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```